# pass class type as parameter c# and used with dictionary

Tags: c#, class, dictionary, parameters

I am create a function to return a dictionary and I want to pass class name through as a parameter. But its gives an error. Code i have written is given below

```
public Dictionary<object, object> GetDetails(Type Classname)
{
    MvcDemoDBEntities db = new MvcDemoDBEntities();
    Dictionary<Classname, object> dict = new Dictionary<Classname, object>();

    var data = (from h in db.People
                select h).ToList();

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        dict.Add(data, true);
    }
    return dict;
}
```

what am i doing wrong 
 and i would like to call this function with a class name dynamically, like this :

```
List<people> list = GetDetails(people).Keys.ToList();
```

people its my class name.

Comment: It's class type, not class name. I edited your question, to be more accurate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

---

### Using Generics

Your current approach will give you much trouble. As you are going to pass a Type object for your class, you will need reflection to be able to create the `Dictionary`.

As an alternative, I propose to you to create a generic method:

```
public Dictionary<object, object> GetDetails<TClass>()
{
    MvcDemoDBEntities db = new MvcDemoDBEntities();
    Dictionary<TClass, object> dict = new Dictionary<TClass, object>();

    var data = (from h in db.People
            select h).ToList();

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        dict.Add(data, true);
    }
    return dict;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
List<people> list = GetDetails<people>().Keys.ToList();
```

---

### Using Type

Of course, this can be done using a Type object, this requiers the use of reflection to be able to create an object of which type we don't know (that object is the dictionary). This is done as follows:

```
public Dictionary<object, object> GetDetails(Type Class)
{
    //Null check
    if (null == Class)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Class");
    }

    MvcDemoDBEntities db = new MvcDemoDBEntities();

    //Get the generic dictionary type:
    Type DictType = typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(Class, typeof(object));

    //Create the dictionary object:
    object dict = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(DictType));

    //Get the Add method:
    var add = DictType.GetMethod("Add", new Type[]{Class, typeof(object)});

    var data = (from h in db.People
            select h).ToList();

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        //add to the dictionary:
        add.Invoke(dict, new object[]{item, true});
    }

    return dict;
}
```

Use like this:

```
List<people> list = GetDetails(typeof(people)).Keys.ToList();
```

---

## Digging deeper

I notice you have this line:

```
var data = (from h in db.People select h).ToList();
```

You may be interested in changing `People` to a property matching the name of the class you pass in. This can only be archived via reflection. In a similar way as how we got the `Add` method of the dictionary, we can get a property from the object `db` which name is given by the argument type.

I'll present this as a second method to be called by the first.

---

### Using Generics

```
public IEnumerable<TClass> GetCollection<TClass>(MvcDemoDBEntities db)
{
    //get the type of db
    var dbType = db.GetType();
    //get the name of the type TClass
    var name = typeof(TClass).Name;
    //get the property
    var prop = dbType.GetProperty(name);
    //read the property and return
    return prop.GetValue(db);
}
```

To use, replace this:

```
var data = (from h in db.People select h).ToList();
```

With this:

```
var data = (from h in GetCollection<TClass>(db) select h).ToList();
```

---

### Using Type

Here the struggle is that we don't know the item type... so I'll use IEnumerable.

```
public IEnumerable GetCollection(MvcDemoDBEntities db, Type Class)
{
    //get the type of db
    var dbType = db.GetType();
    //get the name of the type Class
    var name = Class.Name;
    //get the property
    var prop = dbType.GetProperty(name);
    //read the property and return
    return prop.GetValue(db);
}
```

To use, replace this:

```
var data = (from h in db.People select h).ToList();
```

With this:

```
var data = (from h in GetCollection(db, Class).Cast<object>() select h).ToList();
```

Comment: @NayeemMansoori can you be more specific? Also, I'll edit my answer to present the reflection approach, though it will take me a while.

Comment: I used your function like this ------------------------------ public Dictionary<object, object> GetDetails<TClass>()
        {
            Dictionary<TClass, object> dict = new Dictionary<TClass, object>();
            foreach (var item in dict)
            {
                dict.Add(TClass, true);
            }
            return dict;
        }                                                                    But its gives an error how to add class value in dictionary

Comment: @NayeemMansoori you must use item as the key, not TClass, TClass is the type. See the updated answer. Edit: fixed typo.

Comment: #Theroat my problem is not solve to give you answers

Comment: @NayeemMansoori I'm the one trying to give you answers, for that the more complete my understanding of the problem the better. I take, you have not been able to solve your problem. Since you haven't told me how, or why, my best guess is that it has to do with this line "var data = (from h in db.People select h).ToList();". I'll try to expand my answer to cover as much as I can, with the hope to cover the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to pass the type of your class

```
List<people> list = GetDetails(typeof(people)).Keys.ToList();
```